# .Net 1.0 and 2.0 hybrid application

Tags: .net, .net-2.0, clr, .net-1.1

I have a .Net app with dll's that some of them were compiled with .Net 1.1 and some with 2.0. How does such an application work - isn't there only one runtime for an application? If so which is it? If not how are objects being passed between the runtimes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right in saying that there's only one runtime used in the application. In your case, the whole application needs to use the 2.0 runtime: the 1.1 runtime can't understand 2.0 DLLs, but the 2.0 runtime does know about 1.1 DLLs.